How to parse JSON request body with an array to create a relationship between structs
I'm using Go/Chi to create a REST API.
This is the structure of the JSON payload from the request body:
{
  "name": "John Smith",
  "bornDate": "2020-10-05",
  "books": [
     {
       "title": "Book 1 Title",
       "publishYear": "1989"
     },
     {
       "title": "Book 2 Title",
       "publishYear": "1999"
     }
   ]
}

And here are the structs I'm attempting to impart onto this request:
type AuthorRequest struct{
    Name string `json: "name"`
    BornDate string `json: "bornDate"`
    Books []BookRequest `json: "books"`
}

type BookRequest struct{
    Title string `json: "title"`
    PublishYear string `json: "publishYear"`
}

And I'm attempting to save AuthorRequest and BookRequest down as Author struct and Book struct.
type Author struct{
    Name string
    BornDate time.Time
    Books []Book
}

type Book struct{
    Title string
    PublishYear int32
}

And this is my handler function for this POST request:
func CreateAuthorAndBooks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   // Assume that AuthorRequest is in an api package
   var authorPayload api.AuthorRequest
   decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
   err := decoder.Decode(&authorPayload)

   if err != nil{
     // Logging an error here on missing fields
   }

   var successMessage string = fmt.Sprintf("%v's has %v books: %v", authorPayload.Name, len(authorPayload.Books), authorPayload.Books)
   var response map[string]string = map[string]string{"success": successMessage}
   w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
   
   var err = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
   if err != nil{
     // Logging an internal server error
   }
  // Logic to create Author and its related Book Structs...
}

But for some reason, when I send the above JSON request body and receive a response, there are 0 books and there is an empty slice [] when referencing books.
How do I properly parse and access an array within a JSON request body for a POST request in Go/Chi?

Start by running go vet on your code, your struct tags aren't valid with the extra spaces.

Note however that while your tags are invalid, the field names still happen to match the default matching rules https://go.dev/play/p/zqCduFB9oxw. A real [mre] would probably show what's going wrong.

See duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958451/unmarshal-json-with-space-in-custom-struct-tag, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629731/cant-unmarshall-json-with-key-names-having-spaces, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051979/why-is-go-json-marshal-rejecting-these-struct-tags-what-is-proper-syntax-for-js, etc

The space that you have included after the json struct tag that might be causing problem here removing that space should resolve the problem.
type AuthorRequest struct{
    Name      string        `json:"name"`
    BornDate  string        `json:"bornDate"`
    Books     []BookRequest `json:"books"`
}

type BookRequest struct{
    Title       string `json:"title"`
    PublishYear string `json:"publishYear"`
}

